# Display a many to many relation in sql as list in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, tags

I have some tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Games (
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Tags(
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Tag VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE GamesTags(
    GameId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TagId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GameId, TagId),
    FOREIGN KEY(GameId) REFERENCES Games(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(TagId) REFERENCES Tags(Id)
);
```

How do I make a SELECT query that can output the title of the game in one column and all it's tags separated by comma in another. Example:

```
Title       | Tags                |
-----------------------------------
Fortnite    | survival, action    |
Super Mario | platform, adventure |
```

Comment: Lookup using `join` with `group_concat`...

Comment: This is a presentation issue, so you should just group these together in the application layer if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   A.Title, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.Tag ORDER BY C.Tag ASC SEPARATOR ',') Tags
FROM Games A 
LEFT JOIN GameTags B
ON A.Id=B.GameID
LEFT JOIN Tags C
ON B.TagId=C.Id
GROUP BY A.Title;
```

For insight see:

[MySQL Group By](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

[MySQL Join Made Easy For Beginners](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join)

[MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)